# Calculate a sum of elements of the list from 0 to n-1 and compare with the largest one

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, sum, compare

I'm trying to write a code which will check, if a sum of some combination of elements of a given list is equal to the largest element in this list. I wrote such a code:

```
def function(argument): 

  max_arg = max(argument)
  argument.remove(max_arg)
  for i in argument:

      if sum(argument[0:i+1]) == max_arg:
          return "true"
      else:
          return "false"

print function([1, 2, 3, 6])
```

I get the "false" string (which is an obvious mistake). Could somebody please point out, what's wrong with the above presented code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making several mistakes:

- You are confusing values with indices. The `for` loop gives you the *values from the list*, not indices into the list. Only because your values are integers does your loop not immediately break.

  In other words, `i` is not set to `0`, `1`, `2`, but to `1`, `2` and `3`.
- You *immediately* return `'false'` from the function when you found a combination that doesn't sum to the maximum. The first sum is `3` (value `1` then translates to `sum(argument[0:2])` which produces `3`), but you don't then let the loop continue.

To fix these mistakes, use a loop over the results of the `range()` function and only return `'false'` when you tried all combinations:

```
def function(argument): 
    max_arg = max(argument)
    argument.remove(max_arg)

    for i in range(len(argument)):
        if sum(argument[:i + 1]) == max_arg:
            return "true"
    return "false"
```

Your 'different combinations' are still pretty primitive. You could try and produce all possible combinations of 3 numbers with [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and increasing lengths:

```
from itertools import combinations

def function(argument): 
    max_arg = max(argument)
    argument.remove(max_arg)

    for length in range(1, len(argument) + 1):
        for combo in combinations(argument, length):
            if sum(combo) == max_arg:
                return "true"
    return "false"
```

Now the order in which your elements are arranged no longer matters; `[1, 4, 3, 2, 6]` will return true because `1 + 3 + 2` produces 6.

Demo:

```
>>> function([1, 2, 3, 6])
'true'
>>> function([1, 4, 3, 2, 6])
'true'
>>> function([1, 4, 3, 6])
'false'
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You are always returning in the first loop itself, if the value is equal (which it wont be unless the first element is the largest element , you return `"true"` ) , otherwise you return `"false"`, instead do not return `"False"` immediately, only return `"false"` when you do not find any cases.

And you are using the values as indices, instead you want to enumerate over `argument` and use the index as indices

Example -

```
def function(argument): 
    max_arg = max(argument)
    argument.remove(max_arg)
    for i in range(len(argument)):
        if sum(argument[0:i+1]) == max_arg:
            return "true"
    return "false"

print function([1, 2, 3, 6])
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> def function(argument):
...     max_arg = max(argument)
...     argument.remove(max_arg)
...     for i in range(len(argument)):
...         if sum(argument[0:i+1]) == max_arg:
...             return "true"
...     return "false"
...
>>> print(function([1, 2, 3, 6]))
true
>>> print(function([1, 2, 3, 7]))
false
```

Answer (score 1):

This performs the sum over elements only once:

```
def function(argument):  
  max_arg = max(argument)
  argument.remove(max_arg)
  s = 0
  for i in argument:
      s += i
      if s == max_arg:
          return "true"
  return "false"
```

Examples:

```
>>> function([1, 2, 3, 6])
'true'
>>> function([1, 2, 3, 7])
'false'
>>> function([1, 2, 3, 4, 6])
'true'
```

Comment: what about `function([1, 2, 3, 6, 1])`

Comment: @TheBrofessor That returns `True` which is as I think it should be because  `[1,2,3]` adds up to the maximum element of  6.  Did you interpret it differently?

Comment: Sorry that one works. I meant something like this `[30, 10, 10, 12, 10]`, where s = 10... 20... 32... 42 and returns false

Comment: @TheBrofessor As I understand what the OP asked,  he wanted to sum _"from 0 to n-1"_  (after removing the max).  If that is what he wants, then returning `False` for `[30, 10, 10, 12, 10]` is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Keeping in mind that addition is associative and commutative...

```
from itertools import permutations

def function(argument): 
    max_arg = max(argument)
    argument.remove(max_arg)

    for combo in permutations(argument):
        s = 0
        for element in combo:
            s = s + element
            if s == max_arg:
                return "true"
    return "false"
```

We see that we do not need to find all the possible combinations. We can just find all the permutations of size (n-1) and add up elements until we find one that matches the `max_arg`.

Comment: This may work for the given input, but not for, say, `[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]`; the OP is trying *different combinations*.